# Upgrading to Maverick Owned Me: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am having issue with postgresql have upgrading to Mavericks like many users out there. I was able to install the pg gem.

I ran `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start` and got the response `server starting`.

However, when I try to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, I get the error:

`fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

My database.yml looks like this:

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5


development:
  <<: *common
  host: localhost
  database: vm_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and re-generated from your     development database
# when you run "rake". Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  <<: *common
  host: localhost
  database: vm_test

production:
  <<: *common
  database: vm_production

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

I am not exactly sure why I'm getting this message. Is this an issue with my database.yml or an issue with postgresql? I can't access `psql` because I get prompted for a password and no matter what I try, I keep getting `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed`.

When I run `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status`, I see the message `pg_ctl: no server running`. How do I start my server without a password?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. There were multiple copies of Postgres on my computer from another application. Make sure you delete all copies of postgres before installing from brew.